# Animated Motion Background Effect

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css, animation

I am trying to achieve a look on a Wordpress website which has a moving smoke effect in the background like this example http://hk.qeelin.com/collections/

I have seen that this is in Javascript, but I am unsure how it's working? Does anybody know how this look can be achieved please?

Answer (score 0):

Is an iframe, you can search by `bg-video-player` source code. Is a youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

This website uses two different loop videos to achieve such effect:

[image: video requests]

There are two other ways to do that that comes to my mind right now: canvas + particles and a sequence of .png files.