# Animated webpage background effect

Tags: html, css, css-animations

[Animated Motion Background Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26636186/animated-motion-background-effect)
i have tried the answers from the question above, but not exactly what am looking for, i am looking for a way to create the same background effect like the one on this webpage: https://fonoapi.freshpixl.com/ any tips or how-to on how i can create it? i came across it and wanted to know how i can achieve the same effect or create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That effect has been created using a particle api that can be found on GitHub https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js

It has nothing to do with css and/or css animations, it is basically a particle simulation rendered to a html canvas element.